# Best Library for 3D Protein Structure Visualization and Annotation

Tags: proteins, protein-structure

I have a background in Computer Science and have recently gotten very interested in the field of Protein Engineering. I am trying to build a web app which displays the 3D structure of a protein when I upload a PDB file. I also want to annotate subsequences with unique labels.

As I am very new to the field I am confused about which library to use. Can I use BioPython for everything? Or should I use any other library for 3D structure visualization like 3Dmol.js, NGL Viewer etc?

Any comments/suggestions/feedback would be really helpful guys as I am a beginner in the field of BioML.

Comment: BioPython can't do structure visualization. NGL and LiteMol are obsoleted by [Mol*](https://molstar.org/) – from the same developers. There is venerable [J(S)mol](https://jmol.sourceforge.net/) and its wiki [lists a few other WebGL viewers](https://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Jmol_JavaScript_Object/WebGL#WebGL-based_alternatives_to_JSmol). The newest viewer is [Moorhen](https://moorhen.org/), but it's more for structural biologists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.